# How to freeze some python tests with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, pytest, cx-freeze

I tried to freeze my test code with cx_freeze but I get the following runtime error:

```
  ...
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 457, in version
    return distribution(package).version
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 430, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(package)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 184, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: importlib_metadata
```

This is my setup.py script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import pytest

build_exe_options = {"includes":  pytest.freeze_includes() }

setup(
    name = "runtests",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "runtests",
    executables = [Executable("runtest.py")],
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this exact problem today - it looks like the problem is caused by a change in naming scheme between Python <= 3.7.x and Python >= 3.8.x
In my case, forcing the system to use the 3.8 interpreter did the trick, but depending on your setup it might be the other way around.

This is the post that clued me in: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1487